# Creating and using SOAP based web service in Laravel framework

Tags: web-services, laravel, laravel-4

In Laravel 4 framework, how to create a SOAP based web service. I would like to build a SOA based web application in laravel. Please clarify with an example how to use web service with some step by step examples or links as i am completely new to laravel

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Maybe you can make a REST API? SOAP is becoming pretty outdated.

Comment: @AntoineAugusti If so, how to do that REST. Plz give me an example of doing it in REST.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use "php-wsdl-creator" (also supports SOAP). They have a great tutorial and many demo php files to get you started. It can also easily be implemented in laravel or any other framework for that matter. :)

You can find more information on Google Code: https://code.google.com/p/php-wsdl-creator/

Also note that SOAP requires an extension to be loaded in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

For more recent needs, you should use a Project such as wsdl2phpgenerator or [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator) from WsdlToPhp. This sort of projects, requirable with composer, use an OOP approach and allows to build a SOAP request easily with PHP objects then handle the response just as the request with PHP objects.